# Super and sub modular games

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, reference-request, comparative-statics

I was trying to read up on super and sub modular games. I have started with basic survey papers like the one by Rabah Amir (2005). Research papers assume a lot of common knowledge (the papers that I have been reading jump right into comparative statics), and since I am just starting out on this, I was looking for a text (book or paper) that could help me understand the basics before I jump into more complicated stuff. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you read Jon Levin's [notes on supermodular games](https://web.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Econ%20286/Supermodular%20Games.pdf)?

Comment: I haven't. I will start with this. Thank you very much!